Moving cell data from a table row to another table row in the same sheet
I've recently started using macros in excel and I want to create a macro that can transfer a whole table row (not the whole excel sheet row but a row from a specific table) to another table within the same sheet, based on what row the user has selected. After it has transferred the data from the cells I need it to delete the active row that has been selected and add another row to the new table, that I'm transferring the data to. I've done some self-learning and compiled a code, but when I try to execute it, it runs into a problem with the deletion of the existing table row.
Here's the code that I've compiled:
Sub Task_Done()
'
' Task_Done Macro
'
Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
        Else
            rng.Cut
     
    Range("Table6[[#Headers],[Çàäà÷à]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Çàäà÷à]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(3).Delete
    
       End If
    End With
    
End Sub

Thank you to anyone who can come to aid on this :).

Instead of "it runs into a problem" state the nature of the problem

Agreed - if you're able to post the line of code that generates the problem, or highlight it with a comment above it in the code block or something, this will help other answerers to pinpoint your issues faster in the future.  Iterate through the code step by step with F8 to try and pinpoint where the issue lies if you do not get a hard-stop error.  Can you elaborate a little more on the issue you have in your question?

Thanks for the advice. The code that's highlighted by the debugging tool is "Selection.ListObject.ListRows(3).Delete", It executes every other action in the code perfectly, except, deleting the emptied row in "Table2" when the data is transferred to "Table 2" from "Table 6". The data moves from one group of cells to the other, but the empty row stays and I get an error message. Hopefully that brings more clarity.

Maybe this way:
Sub Task_Done()
'
' Task_Done Macro
'
Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Intersect(Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
    Else
        rng.Cut
     
        Range("Table6[#Headers]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Range("Table2[#Headers]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.ListObject.ListRows(Selection.Row - Range("Table2[#Headers]").Row).Delete
    
    End If
    
End Sub

